# Issue sending POST data to a login form with the character "ñ" (With Curl Works)

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

With curl works perfectly and I can Login.

```
curl 'https://server.com/server.jsp?login' --data 'username=usernamex&PASSWORD=contrase%F1a'
```

contrase%F1a15 means "contraseña15"

but when I try to send the same content with request I recieve the password is incorrect.

```
payload = 'username=usernamex&PASSWORD=contrase%F1a' 
login = "https://server.com/server.jsp?login"
r = requests.post(url=login,data=payload)
print r.text
```

How I can fix that? I try with serveral options. Like payload = {'password':'contraseña15" ..} and using json.dumps, but nothing, Always I recieve the same Result.

Please Help!

EDIT:
I also I try this

```
import urllib2, urllib
url = 'https://server.com/server.jsp?login'
data = urllib.urlencode({'USUARIO':'username','PASSWORD':'contrase%F1a15'})
req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
d = response.read()
print d
```

And nothing, I get the same result. Only works with Curl.

Edit 2:

Something extra

With this I recieve the same result like with requests

```
curl 'https://server.com/server.jsp?login' --data 'USUARIO=username&PASSWORD=contraseña15'
```

But if I Use this ! works perfeclty.

```
curl 'https://server.com/server.jsp?login' --data 'USUARIO=username&PASSWORD=contrase%F1a15'
```

Edit 3:

With PyCurl Works Perfect!

```
import pycurl
c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(c.URL, 'https://server.com/server.jsp?login')
postfields = 'USUARIO=username&PASSWORD=contrase%F1a15'
c.setopt(c.VERBOSE, True)
c.setopt(c.POSTFIELDS, postfields)
c.perform()
c.close()
```

FINALLY! Thanks @mhawke

solution:

```
login_url = 'https://server.com/server.jsp?login'
password = u'contraseña15'.encode('iso-8859-1')
payload = {'username': 'usernamex', 'PASSWORD': password}
r = requests.post(login_url, data=payload)
```

Comment: requests should url encode it automatically for you, try with the`ñ` in there

Comment: I update the original Post, When i send the curl request with the "ñ" I get the same result that with requests. 
But if I send the curl requests with the encoding, works perfectly.

Comment: Please put in the original question what you expect to see when requests works and what you see now that makes you think things are incorrect

Comment: @sigmavirus24 is something with the encoding. With curl works perfect! but with requests dont works, and mhawke found the solution!
Why requests lib dont detect that? I dont know why you you close my thread in github, becaus this could help a tons of people. because some time the utf8 encoding dont works in all the situations.

Comment: @Wu4m4n your question doesn't describe the behaviour you expect to see or what you're seeing with urllib/requests. It's incomplete and will not help others in the community when they find your question.

Comment: @sigmavirus24 but now, you think this solution could help to the requests comunity ? because could be a good idea adding this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try posting the unencoded values like this:

```
login_url = 'https://server.com/server.jsp?login'
payload = {'username': 'usernamex', 'PASSWORD': 'contraseña15'}
r = requests.post(login_url, data=payload)
```

`requests` will handle the url encoding for you. The server should see

```
username=usernamex&PASSWORD=contrase%C3%B1a15
```

in the body of the POST.

**Updated**

With `curl` the posted data appears to be urlencoded ISO-8859-1 text, or similar. With `requests`, the posted data is urlencoded UTF8 data. It appears that the server expects ISO-8859-1 encoding for the request body. Try this:

```
login_url = 'https://server.com/server.jsp?login'
password = u'contraseña15'.encode('iso-8859-1')
payload = {'username': 'usernamex', 'PASSWORD': password}
r = requests.post(login_url, data=payload)
```

With this request the server should now see:

```
username=usernamex&PASSWORD=contrase%F1a15
```

which is the same as that generated by `curl`.

Comment: I try with that. But nothing. I recieve the same result. I get the status code and is 200.

Comment: The result of the requests.
When I am try to login with using curl, works perfect! but when I use request I have some issue. I dont receive the same HTML. I recieve a html related with the password is incorrect. I update the original Post with some experiments.

Comment: Looks like an encoding issue with the request body. See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it in my system and this thing worked:

```
import requests

requests.post(login, {'username':'<your username>', 'password':'<your password>'})
```

The password I entered was exactly the same as that I enter in my form. It worked for me and I got a `response code of 200`.

Comment: I recieve the status and is 200. but I dont know why with curl works and with requests i dont see any good result.

Comment: if it is giving 200 status code that means your authentication was successful. `requests` will get you the desired html data which you will get in `response` in `response.content`

Comment: I update the original Post, I thing is something wrong with the lib requests, because if I send the requests with curl, but without the encoding I receive the same error that I get with requets.

Answer (score 0):

My final review.
The the same URL and the same POST DATA.
With requests dont works, but works in pycurl.

```
import requests
import pycurl


login_url = "https://server.com/server.jsp?login"
postfields = 'username=usernamex&PASSWORD=contrase%F1a'

r = requests.post(login_url,postfields)
#This return a html with relatedd with error Login
print r.text


#And this Works perfectly.
c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(c.URL, login_url)
c.setopt(c.VERBOSE, True)
c.setopt(c.POSTFIELDS, postfields)
c.perform()
c.close()
```